# CollectionView not removing ItemView with TR

Tags: ember.js

In my app, I've got a table of rows, each row containing data. When I click the "delete" button, I want it to remove the row.

The long and the short of it is that when I delete the object from the collection, the view disappears, the object disappears, but the template is left in the table.

If you move the collection view outside a table, replace all the tr's with divs, and all the td's with spans, this bug doesn't happen, and everything works smoothly.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EXEnUZE/4/edit

The above fiddle shows the problem. You should be able to edit the color, but if you delete one, the object itself is gone (as evidenced by the top list), and if you use the Chrome Ember Debugger on it, the view is gone, but the HTML for the row still remains.

Is this an Ember bug? Should I open an issue for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly I'm no pro when it comes to the collection view, but have you contemplated using an each instead?  It seems to be a little less problematic.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EXEnUZE/9/edit

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{view App.PlayerView content=item}}
{{/each}}
```

Honestly it does seem a little buggy, the view itself did call destroy (I tried to manually call destroy on it), but it failed to remove itself from the page(maybe the collection as well, I didn't dig into it much).  So you might submit a bug, or spend a little time digging into it, that's up to you.  I'll keep digging into it as well and update this if I find anything.

Comment: As far as my tests go, it removes it from the collection in Ember Data as well. I don't mind changing it to an if loop, I'm pretty sure I don't actually *need* the collection view. I added it because I thought it looked more idomatic, but if it's causing problems...

Comment: Just as a heads up, changing it to an each worked perfectly inside my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a extra answer, I filed a bug report on Ember for this, and got the following response: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3723

The suggestion of using tagName="table" on it, and then removing the tr's from inside the child views worked perfectly.

Comment: @kingpin2k just tagging you in case you are interested in this. Thanks for the help!